# Year vs Month table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I'm currently working in a sql project using PostgreSQL, now my results look like this:

```
month | year | sales
----- + ---- + -----
  7   | 2019 | 5300
  8   | 2019 | 6600
  9   | 2019 | 7100
  7   | 2020 | 6900
  8   | 2020 | 8800
  9   | 2020 | 9500
```

With this code:

```
select date_part('month', points_reward.created) as mes,
   date_part('year', points_reward.created) as ano,
   sum(available_points) as "sales"
from points_reward
group by 1,2
```

I'm trying to create a table that show me the month vs year like this:

```
      | 2019 | 2020
  --- + ---- + ----
  7   | 5300 | 6900
  8   | 6600 | 8800
  9   | 7100 | 9500
```

Thanks in advance for any hint or help and for taking the time to read.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag. If your question is about PostgreSQL, then you shouldn't tag unrelated database systems like MySQL.

Comment: As a fast shot. Create 2 SELECT statements, one for each year, and use UNION to combine their results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Filter` with `SUM` function will solve your problem.

```
select 
date_part('month', points_reward.created) as "Month",
sum(available_points) filter (where date_part('year', points_reward.created)=2019) "2019",
sum(available_points) filter (where date_part('year', points_reward.created)=2020) "2020"
from points_reward
group by 1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1c550945346c3c5515230f25f15c2c3e)

You can add new columns with further years with same pattern

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select cte1.month, cte1.sales as '2019',cte2.sales as '2020' from
(select month, sum(available_points) as sales from points_reward where year=2019 group by month)
 as cte1 inner join
(select month, sum(available_points) as sales from points_reward where year=2020 group by month)
 as cte2 on cte1.month=cte2.month
order by cte1.month
```